# How to upload InputStream to HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, inputstream, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I have created a **HttpURLConnection** using which i need to upload a file to a specific URL. Below is my code

```
String uURL = "http:some_domain/add";
URL url = new URL(uURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

InputStream iStream = getContent("ABC", "test.json");
```

Now, i have retrieved my content in `iStream` and want to upload it using `OutputStreamWriter`. How can i upload the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your content is text file you can use **OutputStreamWriter**. (It's look like your file is a json)

```
try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8")) {
    String data = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 30}";
    osw.write(data);
    osw.flush();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

If your content is binary file you can use **DataOutputStream**

```
try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os)) {
    byte[] data = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
    dos.write(data);
    dos.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```